# How to make an image clickable in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm recreating my portfolio website using React. The following code snippet works on an html page but when I add it to my new App.js file it doesn't load the image. All files and folders exist in src on the react app.

```html
<a
   href="https://github.com/tylerking841"
   target="_blank"
   rel="noreferrer"
>
   <img id="github" alt="github" src="images\github.png" />
</a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tylerkiingg">
   <img id="linkedin" alt="linkedin" src="images\linkedin.png" />
</a>
```

Was expecting to see [my portfolio footer images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF7z5.png) but got [alt image descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNgRN.png)

Disregard the email icon as that's a JS function I haven't added yet

Comment: Because the paths are relative. If you on `site.com/foo/bar` it will try to load `/foo/images/github.png`. I'm guessing you want to add a slash in front of that path. You can check your web console for 404s, that'll tell you what it is actually trying to load :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure backslashes are allowed in paths (maybe on Windows?). I recommend normal slashes, like in your href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App doesn't recognize the path provided, I'd suggest to import images first and then pass them to the src like this:

```
// import at the top 
import githubLogo from "./images/github.png" // add the correct path 

// in the code
<a
   href="https://github.com/tylerking841"
   target="_blank"
   rel="noreferrer"
>
   <img id="github" alt="github" src={githubLogo}/>
</a>
```

this should work.

Comment: While this might very will fix it, it does not explain the core problem. Maybe add a bit why its not working now, and *why* your answer *does* fix it? :) That way readers can understand the problem next time they encounter it

Comment: My Reactjs is a bit rusty, but I'm guessing you need to know the src relative to that file, instead of the url, leaving the creation of absolute paths to React?

Comment: Late response but thank you this fixed my issue 